# Angular 7: How can I reduce the vendorjs (@angular/... packages) size to improve page load time?

Tags: angular, angular7, filesize, vendor, page-load-time

So, I have searched for this here, and tried most of the solutions. But, I didn't get any concrete ones.
The problem is the vendorjs size is around 1 MB, if I consider only the Angular (core?) packages, and this file gets loaded before anything is displayed on screen. Which means, we have to wait for 1 Mb+ files to be served from server, before the user (the king) can do anything useful in the app.
I don't know if I'm doing something wrong. If I can't reduce the size, is there any other workaround?
I don't care about the size, as long as the app loads quickly, and (sideload?) these core packages.
The actual size is much more, but I want to focus on the Angular packages.

Please don't give any solutions related to gzip, because (I could be wrong here), this needs to be setup in the server? and I don't have control over the server configurations.

I used source-map-explorer to come up with the sizes:
[vendorjs-size-distribution](https://i.stack.imgur.com/x2EhD.png)

EDIT: BTW this is from the package json:
"@agm/core": "1.0.0-beta.5",
"@angular/animations": "7.0.3",
"@angular/cdk": "7.0.3",
"@angular/common": "7.0.3",
"@angular/compiler": "7.0.3",
"@angular/core": "7.0.3",
"@angular/elements": "^7.2.0",
"@angular/flex-layout": "7.0.0-beta.19",
"@angular/forms": "7.0.3",
"@angular/http": "7.0.3",
"@angular/material": "7.0.3",
"@angular/platform-browser": "7.0.3",
"@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "7.0.3",
"@angular/router": "7.0.3",

Comment: Upgrade to angular 10 it should reduce the size

Comment: read https://indepth.dev/angular-with-ivy-build-performance-review/

Comment: I cannot upgrade the current project. Need a workaround with Angular 7.

Comment: the main feature of the angular update were the size reduction since you cant do that i would suggest try reducing the library that is used.

Comment: I will try to remove some from the @angular packages. But, I don't think it will make much of a dent in this 'big' problem. @angular/material package in itself is above 300 kb.

Comment: can u share your angular.json, as well. From what I see you are using Kendo UI as well as angular material UI. Try to stick to one UI framework will reduce the size in a way.

Comment: I have met the same problem with Angular application size , and this is what I did: 1、remove unnecessary polyfills for browers I don't have to support,  2、use lazy-loading modules feature to divide initial files into more pieces some of which could be loaded later, 3、add a loading process spinner to have a better user experience.

Comment: @gkrthk: Yes I'm using both material and kendo styling. We use kendo grid, so we had to use the kendo default theme as well. Yes, that is another problem I'm trying to solve. That will be for another post :)

Comment: Try using the differents options when use [ng build](https://v7.angular.io/cli/build), e.g. `ng build --prod`  or `ng build --prod--buildOptimizer`. You can also use [lazy modules](https://v7.angular.io/guide/router#lazy-loading-route-configuration) to load at first only the neccesary (note: all the links are about docs in Angular 7)

Comment: @Eliseo I have been using those commands before I posted the question. Maybe I will try  ng build --prod--buildOptimizer again , but I don't think it would make any difference. I have also been using lazy loading prior to posting the said question. If it wasn't for lazy loading, the load times would have been unbearable, hehe.

Comment: @Eliseo ng build --prod-optimizer doesn't do much. Seems vendor chunk needs to be disabled for it to work. But, it adds that size to the main bundle. So, not much difference anyways.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, I have upgraded to Angular 11.
So, I don't know about the internals. But I did not notice much improvements (that's subjective). But, my belief is Angular core packages in itself has 500kb size. And this gets loaded before any page paint.
I will post webpack-analyzer results when I get the time.
So, as far as I know, there is no way around this :)

P.S. This hasn't effected our project much as it is internal app, and network is good enough most of the time.

Edit:
Had some issues with source-map-explorer so ended up

using webpack-bundle-analyzer to get bundle sizes:
[@angular bundle size](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pKER6.jpg)
[core.js size](https://i.stack.imgur.com/34ZFL.jpg)

@angular:991.56kb

- material:398.24kb
- core.js:117.8kb
- cdk:178.49kb

Comment: Please provide additional details in your answer. As it's currently written, it's hard to understand your solution.

Comment: I will post webpack-analyzer results when I get the time.